# Woocommerce custom product type product not adding to add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom product type same as variable product type in woocommerce and added a custom template for the product type

I have listed the product type variations in frontend but when I select the variation and click add to cart button the product is not adding to cart

It shows the error "Sorry, this product cannot be purchased."

I have checked the add to cart button in this the value is not updating

Can anybody help me to add the product to add to cart here is the link of the product https://demowhistle.com/poster_plugin/product/test-product/